# Trying to copy a file from local RPi to remote RPi in a Python script using scp and SSH key pairs

Tags: python, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, scp

I am able to copy files in the terminal on my local pi to my remote pi using scp and SSH keys without a password prompt
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K81pE.png)

But when I use os.system to run the same command in a Python script, the terminal interrupts the script and prompts me for the password to pi@192.168.0.15.

Just spent hours trying different SSH key pair tutorials trying to fix this to no avail. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
# Simple example of reading the MCP3008 analog input channels and printing
# them all out.
# Author: Tony DiCola
# License: Public Domain
import time

# Import SPI library (for hardware SPI) and MCP3008 library.
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MCP3008
import os

# Software SPI configuration:
# CLK  = 18
# MISO = 23
# MOSI = 24
# CS   = 25
# mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK, cs=CS, miso=MISO, mosi=MOSI)

# Hardware SPI configuration:
SPI_PORT   = 0
SPI_DEVICE = 0
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE))
num = 1

print('Reading MCP3008 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')
# Print nice channel column headers.
print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*range(8)))
print('-' * 57)
# Main program loop.
while True:
    # Read all the ADC channel values in a list.
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
        # The read_adc function will get the value of the specified channel (0-7).
        values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)
    # Print the ADC values.
    print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*values))
    # Check if distance of object has increased, take a picture if it has.
    if values[0] < 100:
        num = num + 1
        imagename = str(num)
        os.system("raspistill -vf -ex night -o "+imagename) 
        os.system("scp /home/pi/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008/examples/"+imagename+" pi@192.168.0.15:/home/pi/Pictures")
    else:
        # Pause for half a second.
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Please rerun `scp` with the `-v` option (`scp -v /home/pi/...`) both interactively and through your script, then [edit] your question to include the verbose output from each case.

Comment: I figured it out from the info given by the `-v` option. It was looking for the identity file in the wrong place (`/root/.ssh/id_rsa` instead of `/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa`) so I used scp's `-i` option to fix it: `os.system("scp -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa /home/pi/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008/examples/"+imagename+" pi@192.168.0.15:/home/pi/Pictures")`